# Hbase table split region stuck, how to solve

Tags: hbase, hadoop2

My hbase version is 1.1.2.2.5, which is installed via ambari.

There are 2000 hbase table carpass online regions, and there are 800 split regions.
After observing for a long time, it was found that the split regions increased continuously and did not decrease. This table is still importing data constantly, how can I solve this problem.

By the way, I also implemented split carpass in the hbase shell, and the online regions increased from more than 1600 to more than 2,000.

carpass Description
'carpass',{NAME=>'e',TTL=>'63072000 SECONDS(730 DAYS)'},{NAME=>'e1',TTL=>'63072000 SECONDS(730 DAYS)'}

help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the number of regions you should do these:

- Increase region size
- Enable Compression
- Merge regions using Hbase shell for example
- Disable Hbase region normalizer